# Load a listview with data

Tags: android

Im trying to load some strings into a listview, ill get to seperate classes for the data later. I just want to display some text right now, but i seem to be doing it wrong:

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, aList , R.layout.main, 
                new String[] { "test", "test", "test", "test" }, 
                new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.item_time, R.id.item_date });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            final ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: im not seeing any errors, it simply does not display data

Answer (score 0):

Your `aList` is empty, so no data is displayed. Youd should populate it in order to see any data.